# MAAS HA config switching gateway on failover

Tags: networking, server, maas, dhcp, high-availability

I am using 16.04 Ubuntu and MAAS 2.1.2, So I have setup two MAAS servers that failover to each other. Everything is working how is should. The only problem is, you have to manually reset the gateway on failover. If one server goes away and that server was set in the GUI to be the gateway for the private network to use for DHCP/PXE, nodes won't be able to get out to the internet unless you manually reset the IP to the gateway of the server that is still active.

Is there any sort of mechanized way to switch the gateway on fail over? Maybe some sort of network change/route? I could script the change on failover with a MAAS command, but I would like to avoid this.

Thanks,
Chris

[MAAS Network Image](https://7cb00a67-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/openstackinthebasement3/maasha/mass%20net.PNG?attachauth=ANoY7cpmd8GHsi26bOy6qsVag0lgrpBL6PpyUk1zZWMZx5RyZmnTfg9AuTaQ4ZgozK0OUyHItqWX8chtNq_7i2ZcjEx7OdrKFslcxkyA-Bfl1Yf0no_2zfuh8o37y6ij4DSh2RgcoJTtpLMsgn-f7JfietXbCqSGdDMElKxzFrRZteWa-dlo-BjHj659dP33hr6L--vC1wacOzDShPzL-r3MD-SuBBgB4NLW4HhHB8evB-VVfWU2934%3D&attredirects=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your using the MAAS controllers as the gateway to the internet I would setup a VIP between the two. This would allow all deployed machines to be able to talk to the gateway no matter which MAAS controller is done. There is documentation on how to do this with MAAS in the documentation, [Manage HA](https://docs.ubuntu.com/maas/2.1/en/manage-ha).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using that documentation to configure this setup. I do have a VIP configured for this. What parameters in the VIP config would allow me to use 2 gateways in a failover scenario? The VIP works great for using 1 IP to access both regions, just not sure how to make it swap gateways.

Comment: From your description I believe your gateways are the controllers. If that is the case just go to the "Subnets" tab and click on the subnet that deployed machines are getting their IP addresses from. Then change the "Gateway IP" to be the VIP. You will have to re-deploy your machines, but once deployed they will point to that new VIP for the gateway. You could also just modify the /etc/network/interfaces on already deployed machines if you do not want to re-deploy.

Comment: Interesting, I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: I was thinking about the main VIP I have for my rack controllers. I added a second one for my private network and it is working great. Thank you.